# Reason behind choosing the invariant states for an operator which commutes with an adiabatic Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-spin

In the section 4.1 of [Quantum Computation by Adiabatic Evolution](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0001106v1.pdf), Farhi et al proposes a quantum adiabatic algorithm to solve the $2$-SAT problem on a ring. To compute the complexity of the algorithm the authors computed the energy gap between the ground and first excited states of the 
adiabatic Hamiltonian.

The adiabatic Hamiltonian is defined as 
$$
\tilde{H} (s) = (1-s) \sum^n_{j=1}(1-\sigma^{(j)}_x) + s \sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{2} (1-\sigma^{(j)}_z \sigma^{(j+1)}_z )
$$

To prove the correctness of the algorithm, the authors consider an operator which negates the value of the bits.
$$
G = \prod^n_{j=1}\sigma^{(j)}_x
$$

Then on page 13, it is mentioned that $[G, \tilde{H}(s)] = 0$. The authors say the following.

> Since $G |x = 0\rangle = |x = 0\rangle$ and $[G, \tilde{H}(s)] = 0$,
>   we can restrict our attention to states that are invariant under $G$
>   such as (4.4).

I do not follow the reasoning here. Why are $G |x = 0\rangle = |x = 0\rangle$ and $[G, \tilde{H}(s)] = 0$ sufficient reason to overlook other states while computing the energy gap between the ground and first excited states of the adiabatic Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 2):

Let $[G,H]=0$, and consider an eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$ of $H$, 
$$
H|\psi\rangle = E\psi\rangle\ .
$$
Then, $|\psi'\rangle := G|\psi\rangle$ is also an eigenstate of $H$ with the same eigenvalue, since
$$
H|\psi'\rangle = HG|\psi\rangle = GH|\psi\rangle = EG|\psi\rangle = E|\psi'\rangle\ .
$$
Thus, also $|\chi\rangle = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\psi\rangle + |\psi'\rangle)$ is an eigenstate of $H$ with eigenvalue $E$, and
$$
G|\chi\rangle 
= \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(G|\psi\rangle + G|\psi'\rangle)=
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\psi'\rangle + |\psi\rangle) = |\chi\rangle\ ,
$$
i.e., $|\chi\rangle$ is invariant under $G$.

Thus, if you care about the gap (which is a difference of two energies), there are always symmetric eigenstates with those energies, which is why you can restrict to symmetric states.

Comment: I would like to know why considering only the invariant states is sufficient.

Comment: @OmarShehab Sufficient **for what**?  I assume it's talking about the ground state and/or its energy.  With the above argument, these states allow you to obtain a ground state (and furthermore, if it is unique, it must be invariant).  But you have to be more precise with your question if you want more precise answers.

Comment: I am sorry for not clarifying it. Now I have mentioned in the question that the purpose is  to compute the energy gap between the ground and first excited states of the adiabatic Hamiltonian.

Comment: The gap is the difference of two eigen-energies.  As I have explained before, for each eigenstate there is a symmetric one with the same energy.  That's why you can restrict to symmetric ones.

Comment: In that last formula, $G|\chi\rangle = |\chi\rangle$ follows only if $G^2 = I$ (which it does), isn't it?

Comment: @udrv Absolutely; the discussion is for the case $G^2=I$ as in the original question.  In the case of a more general group with representation $U_g$, one has to define $|\chi\rangle$ as the average over the entire group, $|\chi\rangle \propto \sum U_g|\psi\rangle$.

Comment: Got it, I took your setting to be more general than you meant it to be.